# Python, How to delete brackets in the column of the data frame while there's strings between brackets

Tags: python

Python, How to delete brackets in the column of the data frame while there's strings between brackets.

I have a data frame named as df_movies and looks like :

```
  movieId    title                   genres
0   1      Toy Story (1995)          Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
1   2      Jumanji (1995)            Adventure|Children|Fantasy
2   3      Grumpier Old Men (1995)   Comedy|Romance
3   4      Waiting to Exhale (1995)  Comedy|Drama|Romance
4   5      Father of the Bride Part II (1995)   Comedy
```

I want to have only the year number in the title. The result should like:

```
1995
1995
1995
1995
1995
```

Q1:  How should I get the above desired result?

Q2: I tried originally to replace "( )" to blank, and then split each row by space and then take the last item in the list.

However,  I tried several codes below, none of them worked

```
try 1:
df_movies["title"].str.replace("(","").replace(")","")

result:(only take the first one)
0                                Toy Story 1995)

try 2:
Title = df_movies["title"]
Title = Title.replace("(","")
Title = Title.replace(")","")
Title

result:(only take the first one)
0                                Toy Story (1995)

However, for try 2, if I only type
Title = df_movies["title"]
Title = Title.replace("(","")
it showed as:
0                                Toy Story 1995)
```

How can I revise that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.str.extract`:

```
df['title'].str.extract(r'\((.*)\)')
```